# Javascript compare timestamps

Tags: javascript, sorting, timestamp

I am trying to sort a two-dimensional array by a timestamp column Descending. This collumn (index 11) is in the format: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'. I have tried multiple things. According to the topics I've read, this code should work:

```
 List.sort(function(x, y){
     return Date.parse(y[11]) - Date.parse(x[11]);
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That will work on up-to-date browsers that support the only-recently-defined input format for `Date.parse` (prior to ES5, it was just "parse whatever `Date#toString` spits out").

Although never spec'd, older browsers will support it with `/` rather than `-` in the date, so:

```
List.sort(function(x, y){
     return Date.parse(y[11].replace(/-/g, '/')) - Date.parse(x[11].replace(/-/g, '/'));
});
```

Always test on your target browsers, of course, because again this was never specified.

For example, on IE8 and earlier:

```
display(Date.parse("2012-06-01 14:22:17"));
```

...is `NaN`, but:

```
display(Date.parse("2012/06/01 14:22:17"));
```

...is `1338556937000`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Wasted so much time on this oneliner. You made my day!

Comment: @user1365889: No worries, glad that helped! Best,

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already got the strings in a perfect format to compare them, I'd skip the date parsing altogether:

```
List.sort(function(x, y){
     return y[11] > x[11] ? 1 : -1;
});
```

although for completeness 0 should be returned in case of equal strings

Comment: +1 Very good point, but I'd show the complete version, and cache the access (since you'll need to do it twice).